# How to test passport LocalStrategy with jest

Tags: express, testing, jestjs, passport.js

Stock with express passport LocalStrategy test, probably on mocking request.

```
test('should Test password Login auth', async (done) => {
  const response = jest.fn((arg)=> console.log('args', arg));
  const next = jest.fn();
  let mockReq = {body: { username: "test@gmail.com", password: "tets"}}
  let mockRes = {send: function(ats){console.log("mockResFunc", ats), response()}};

  passport.authenticate('local', ()=> response())(mockReq, mockRes);

  expect(next).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(response).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

but callback is never called as well as i didn't found password and username goes to  passport function. Does anyone ideas how to mock  credentials using jest(i think here is clue)?

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    async function(username, password, done) {
            const existingUser = await User.findOne({ 'email' :  username })
            console.log('credits', username, password, existingUser.email)
    if (existingUser) {
        let validUsr = existingUser.validPassword(password);
        if (existingUser && validUsr) {
            console.log('passport',existingUser.email)
          return done(null, existingUser);
        }
    }
    return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong credentials.' });
    }
  ));
```

Comment: If someone get similar task, calback wasnt called for me becouse of model findOne, which i solved my mocking this method with mockingoose.

Answer (score -1):

Dont write a mock function for something like local strategy, write an actual function

```
const request = require('supertest')
const app = require('../server/app')
describe('Login', () => {
  it('should fail with incorrect credentials', async () => {
    const res = await request(app)
      .post('/auth/login')
      .send({
        email: 'dummy',
        password: 'demo'
      })
    expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(401)
    expect(res.body).toHaveProperty('message')
  })

  it('should succeed with correct credentials', async () => {
    const res = await request(app)
      .post('/auth/login')
      .send({
        email: 'demo',
        password: 'demo'
      })
    expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200)
    expect(res.body).toEqual({ email: 'demo' })
  })
})

describe('Logout', () => {
  it('should logout successfully', async () => {
    const res = await request(app).post('/auth/logout')
    expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200)
    expect(res.body).toEqual({ ok: true })
  })
})
```